# tftp an application using uefi shell

Tags: bootloader, bios, firmware, uefi

I want to flash and upgrade my tianocore boot loader from the uefi shell.
Is it possible in this manner ?

1. download the tianocore firmware image from a server using tftpboot on uefi shell.
2. Erasing the NOR flash and writing the new firmware image on the NOR flash again on uefi shell.

Are there any uefi shell commands that can perform the above operations or is there any other way to do that without writing a new application ?

Thanks,

devendra

Answer (score 1):

There are no ready standard EFI Shell commands to update UEFI firmware from an image located on a server. You would have to write a Shell app that uses Tianocore networking services to download the image and use capsule services to initiate the firmware update (see UEFI spec chapter 7.5.3).

Note that the firmware image would have to be in a form of UEFI Capsule, produced and signed by the firmware vendor - it is not simply a binary image of the NOR flash. Due to security reasons there is no way to flash the NOR flash image directly and there are no tools or methods to circumvent this.

Comment: It might also be useful to add that not all UEFI systems support the capsule services (maybe because the firmware is too old, is broken, or had it intentionally removed), so even if you wrote your own shell app, it might not work. However, some of the major PC vendors DO offer their own proprietary way to remotely reflash the UEFI... that might be worth investigating.

Comment: UEFI firmware that does not support capsule update is broken and is not worth investigating, although you are right, there may be such products out there and writing a Shell app for such device would be a waste of time. I am also not aware of PC vendors who offer the firmware-level remote reflash feature as part of their product.

Comment: Normally, PC vendors provide an OS-level app that pulls the new firmware capsule from the vendor's server, installs it in RAM, and triggers a reset. Then firmware on boot picks up the capsule, validates it, and flashes.

Comment: I actually think more large PC vendors are shying away from the generic capsule support now, since it has been shown to be problematic from a security perspective. You are right though, PC vendors typically provide their own OS level app to do the update. As for remote update, the main way I have seen this done is through a management controller (whether it is a full BMC or just the integrated Intel ME support). It's not a reliable method for any kind of machine, but if you're looking at a specific vendor, it might be worth checking out.